# High frequency response of capacitors

Tags: capacitor, ac, dc, frequency-response

I have studied the fact that the capacitor does not like a varying voltage across its terminals, and it acts as a short circuit initially so that there is no voltage drop across it. If this is true, then why does it acts a short circuit (or a low impedance connection) in case of AC signals, which have alternating or changing voltages every moment?

Comment: When your voltage is constantly changing, every moment is "initially". This is an oversimplification but it might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: @Felthry  , Sir, Voltage is not always changing constantly, it may be changing sinsoidally which is very common.

Comment: sinusoidally varying is still constantly varying. Here I'm using "constantly" to mean "at all points in time"; not the mathematical sense of the word constant. Apologies, I should have been clearer. It seems like English isn't your first language and I should have considered that when writing!

Comment: I did not understand why you say every moment is "initially". That's too non-intuitive.

Comment: @JohnCena, if I hand you a circuit and tell you to start analyzing it, how will you decide what moment is the "initial" moment of the analysis. It could be any time you choose to start your analysis, therefore any moment in time is just the same as the "initial" moment as far as the capacitor is concerned.

Comment: @The Photon Ok Sir. I got the thing. What I thought that initial time means when the capacitor has zero charge or fully charged and then connected in circuit. At intermediate time it has variable charge and therefore we can't say any intermediate time as initial time.

Comment: @rdtsc Your statement is totally irrelevant to what I asked. I never asked about parasitic properties of capacitor. But thanks for providing the information.

Answer (score 5):

> capacitor does not like the fact that voltage is changed across it since it acts as a short circuit initially

I don't know what the capacitor likes or doesn't like, but I think your reasoning is backwards.

First, we usually say "the voltage across an ideal capacitor cannot change instantly" rather than say what the capacitor likes or doesn't like (we might say the capacitor doesn't "like" having a voltage higher than its WV rating across it, or a current greater than its ripple current rating through it, because those things will damage the capacitor).

Second, the reason for the voltage not changing instantly is the capacitor's defining relation:

$$V = \frac{Q}{C}$$

This means that in order to change the voltage (V) instantly, you'd have to change the separated charge (Q) instantly. That would require delivering an infinite current through the capacitor (if only for an instant).

Similarly, the reason the capacitor "acts as a short circuit" for short time periods in a transient analysis is again that its voltage waveform can't be discontinuous without its current waveform including singularities, not the other way around.

> If this is true than why does it acts a short circuit(or low impedance) in case of AC signals which have alternating or changing voltages every moment.

Remember

$$V=\frac{Q}{C}$$

Another thing this means is that for the voltage to change quickly (as in a high frequency AC signal), the charge must be moved quickly in and out of the capacitor plates.

Charge moving quickly means large currents.

And large currents through it producing only small voltage changes is exactly what it means to say that a component has a low impedance. When the impedance of the capacitor is much lower than that of other components in our circuit, then we say the capacitor acts like a short circuit.

Comment: Sir, according to definition Ic=C*dV_c/dt. The capacitor give current when voltage is changing which denies the fact it don't want voltage fluctuations across it. I seem to be really confused Sir. Please explain the fact.

Comment: It doesn't mean the capacitor gives current when voltage is changing. It means whatever is trying to change the voltage must deliver sufficient current. If dV/dt is high, that means it needs to deliver high current. Again, this is exactly what it means for something to have a low impedance.

Comment: Sir, why does it need to deliver high current?

Comment: Because I = C dV/dt, and dV/dt is high.

Comment: That's according to formula but according to intuition?

Comment: Just what I already wrote in the answer: "for the voltage to change quickly (as in a high frequency AC signal), the charge must be moved quickly in and out of the capacitor plates". If I move a certain charge slowly (say once or twice per second) can you see why that requires less (average) current than if I move it quickly (millions of times per second)?

Comment: @JohnCena Intuition does not arise from thin-air. For a capacitor the intuition that most people eventually acquire (without thinking about the formula) is still fundamentally based on I = \$C\frac{dv}{dt}\$. That formula holds-good for all scenarios.

Comment: I think the answers explains well everything. The thing is that I should write down every important point in a paper and then analyse every points. Also do I need to keep all this points while solving AC Analysis of a Capacitor or formula is enough?

Comment: Intuition is that capacitor is a short circuit for AC and open circuit for DC

Comment: @Photon. Yes Sir, I got it. The formula itself explains the phenomenon in capacitor. I am satisfied now. To produce more voltage change in C we need to give high current(which is also changing in nature).

Comment: @The Photon  Sir, please explain me this part of your answer "Similarly, the reason the capacitor "acts as a short circuit" for short time periods in a transient analysis is again that its voltage waveform can't be discontinuous without its current waveform including singularities, not the other way around."

Comment: @Andy Aka What is squared and fixed? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

> I have studied the fact that capacitor does not like the fact that voltage is changed across it since it acts as a short circuit initially so that there is no voltage drop across it.

I find that a good(ish) way to think if it when analysing schematics. A capacitor tends to maintain the voltage across it whereas an inductor tends to maintain the current through it.

The voltage drop across it will be whatever the voltage across it was at the instant the change begins. This may be zero but it may be some other DC value.

> If this is true than why does it acts a short circuit (or low impedance) in case of AC signals which have alternating or changing voltages every moment.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLZkny.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A DC blocking capacitor on an audio signal. The output is biased to 2.5 V to feed into a 0 - 5 V ADC.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The simulator waveforms.*

Notice that the output of the circuit is always 2.5 V above the input. The capacitor, if you like, is maintaining a constant 2.5 V across it.

Note that if we froze the input at the 1 V peak, for example, that the right hand side of C1 would discharge through R2 back to 2.5 V and the C1 voltage would be 2.5 - 1 = 1.5 V. On restart of the sine the OUT signal would be centred around 1.5 V for the first cycle but gradually rise back to the 2.5 V equilibrium.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try yet another path for you to consider, among the many here. Sometimes, this helps. Sometimes, just the opposite. Only you'll know for sure.

Suppose you had a voltage source connected across a capacitor and decided to make a finite, but instant, change in the voltage (call it \$\Delta V\$) to some new value then the capacitor's voltage would also have to instantly change with it. But to do that, an infinite current would be required. So from this thought experiment we would expect that the impedance of a capacitor is zero. But this is only true because we assumed an instant change in the voltage, which is equivalent to an infinite frequency. And in that case, the impedance of a capacitor really is zero.

We can't supply finite currents or make instant changes in voltages and, besides, electronics devices work with various realistic frequencies and not infinite ones. So the above thought experiment isn't broadly useful, anyway.

What we do know is that an AC voltage can be represented as a rotation of a real-valued vector rotating around, where the tip describes a circle and where the angle of rotation at any given moment is \$\omega\:t\$ (in radians.) You can draw that out on a piece of paper, easy enough. Just make the arrow length equal to the peak voltage of the AC, or \$V_0\$. Then spin it around to describe that circle. If your voltage is based upon the sine, starting at the arrow at \$0^\circ\$ along the positive x-axis, and sweeping it around the circle counter-clockwise such that \$\theta=\omega\:t\$, then the y-axis value at any given \$t\$ is the instantaneous voltage of your source. (If your voltage is based upon the cosine, then the x-axis value at any given \$t\$ is the instantaneous voltage of your source.) It's a simple way to visualize an alternative perspective that still provides the right values.

There's a truly wonderful relationship, often just called "Euler's" for short, that is this:

$$e^{i\:\omega\:t}=\operatorname{cos}\left(\omega\:t\right)+i\operatorname{sin}\left(\omega\:t\right)$$

(Here, and as follows, I'll stay with the mathematician's use of \$i\$ rather than the electroncs' replacement of \$j=i\$.)

This relationship can be used equally well to represent the above idea using the circle, if we are plotting on the complex plane instead of the usual \$\left(x,y\right)\$ plane I'd indicated earlier. Just imagine the new imaginary y-axis as being roughly the same as the earlier y-axis. Then I think you can see how the new approach using Euler's achieves an equivalent representation. But it has the huge advantage of being compact (terse and easy to write) and amenable to derivatives and integrals used in calculus (but also used to describe capacitors and inductors as used in electronics.)

It's not critical whether we treat a sinusoidal voltage as a cosine or sine, so long as we remain consistent. So it is perfectly fine to consider a sinusoidal voltage as \$V\left(t\right)=V_0\:e^{i\:\omega\:t}\$, keeping in mind that we will be selecting only the real part (for cosine) or the imaginary part (for sine.) Assuming \$V\left(t\right)\$ across the capacitor, the current in a capacitor is \$I\left(t\right)=C\:\frac{\text{d}\:V\left(t\right)}{\text{d}t}\$. But \$\frac{\text{d}\:V\left(t\right)}{\text{d}t}=V_0\:i\:\omega\:e^{i\:\omega\:t}\$. So it follows that:

$$Z_C=\frac{V\left(t\right)}{I\left(t\right)}=\frac{V_0\:e^{i\:\omega\:t}}{C\:V_0\:i\:\omega\:e^{i\:\omega\:t}}=\frac{1}{i\:\omega\:C}$$

The amazing thing is that this all "just works." (Just remember now that in electronics \$j\$ is used in lieu of \$i\$.)

One of the things to keep in mind is that with real numbers, when you multiply it is kind of like "stretching" or "shrinking." So if you multiply by 1, you don't stretch or shrink. But if you multiply by some other factor, then you will be doing one or the other.

But with complex number multiplication, the operation combines two things (as we imagine in our minds, anyway): stretching and rotation. I only mention that because it's something you'll encounter later on. However, in the above case, we've focused only on the rotation part of it.

In complex numbers, multiplying by \$i\$ is the same as rotating by \$90^\circ\$. So when you look at the above equation for \$Z_C\$, the imaginary factor you see in that equation means in some sense "shifted by \$90^\circ\$." In other words, you'd expect the current waveform to be shifted by \$90^\circ\$ relative to the voltage.

Whether shifted "backward" or "forward" is a matter of the sign (or whether the \$i\$ is in the numerator or denominator.) Rather than make you memorize which sign means what in every case, I'd rather just provide a qualitative description that always provides a clear guide. Since we took the derivative to get the current, it follows that we'd need to reverse things and instead take the integral of the current to get the voltage back. Because integrals with respect to time inherently "*take time*" this means that the voltage "takes time" and will therefore appear to "lag" the current by \$90^\circ\$ if you look at a plot over time of both.

It's easier for me to remember only that when I'm comparing \$x\left(t\right)\$ and \$y\left(t\right)\$, where \$y\left(t\right)=\int x\left(t\right)\:\text{d}t\$, then this means that \$y\left(t\right)\$ must lag \$x\left(t\right)\$. It has to because the integral "takes time."

For a very interesting and very visual (not algebra-heavy) video that I think may help a lot in understanding better some of what I wrote above, see [Euler's and an intro to group theory](https://youtu.be/mvmuCPvRoWQ) by 3blue1brown (Grant Sanderson.)

Comment: That really helped me Sir. Such a great answer. Thanks. Very helpful and mathematically proven.

Answer (score 1):

A capacitor is perfectly willing, in its small-minded way, to change the voltage between its plates.

In an ideal capacitor, the dV = dT * I/C has worked fine for me, for decades.

I've memorized "1 amp into 1 Farad for 1 second, produces 1 volt change in the capacitor voltage." and life is good.

And 1 milliamp into 1picoFarad produces 1 volt change in 1 nanoSec.

In a realistic capacitor, with leads/wires connecting to the plates, the added inductance does cause the circuit to be a resonator; fortunately the losses inside a realistic capacitor do cause dampening; however, in a VDD network for your various stages or modules, you may need to add dampening resistors (1 ohm) or exploit the PCB resistance to dampen; PCB foil is 0.000500 ohms per square (any size square) at room temperature; you don't want your power supply bypass capacitors to be ringing.

Comment: Yes Sir, I got it. The formula itself explains the phenomenon in capacitor. I am satisfied now. To produce more voltage change in C we need to give high current(which is also changing in nature).

Comment: @ John Cena Even LOW currents, fixed, will charge or discharge the capacitor and thus cause a changing voltage.

Comment: OK. so what am i missing?

Comment: How does that 2nd bit of math, involving 1mA into 1pF, give you some understanding?

Comment: What do you want to convey?